# Sort on controller name or tag with NSwag and C#

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, nswag

I'm having a ASP.Net Core solution for which I want to use Swagger. For this I use the Nuget package NSwag (Assembly NSwag.AspNetCore, Version=11.20.1.0). In my Configuration of the app I have the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app..UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(settings =>
        {
            settings.GeneratorSettings.DefaultPropertyNameHandling = PropertyNameHandling.CamelCase;
            settings.PostProcess = document =>
            {
                document.Info.Version = $"v{typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Version.Major}";
                document.Info.Title = "Test Api";
                document.Info.Description = "Sample API";
                document.Info.TermsOfService = "None";
                document.Info.Contact = new NSwag.SwaggerContact
                {
                    Name = "Person",
                    Email = "Email"
                };
            };
        });
}
```

When I run this, I see correctly all controllers and corresponding methods, but it is not sorted alphabetically.

I already tried the following:

- Add TagSorter to settings:

  ```
  app.UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(settings =>
      {
          ...
          settings.TagSorter = "alpha";
          ...
      });
  ```
- Add ApisSorter to settings:

  ```
  app.UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(settings =>
      {
          ...
          settings.ApisSorter = "alpha";
          ...
      });
  ```

But these changes result in the same output. How can I achieve the sorting?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But after upgrading NSwag.AspNetCore -> 12.0.8 (latest version at time of writing) and replacing the methods that are now `Obsolete` it worked with

```
s.TagsSorter = "alpha";
s.OperationsSorter = "alpha";
```

Comment: When I upgrade I get an error when running my project that I cannot use UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(), but use instead UseSwaggerUi3(), and when I then go to my Swagger page I get the error: Failed to load API definition.

Comment: Hmm I use `app.UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(...)`. `UseSwaggerUi3` is marked as obsolete with the comment _Use UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer instead._


**EDIT**: Never mind, there were one overload of `UseSwaggerUi3` that wasn't marked with obsolete